# JavaScript Default Parameters: passing no values

Tags: javascript

```js
let add = (a = 0,b = 0) => {
    return a+b;
};

console.log(add(5,2));
```

What I expected was: `0`

and the result is: `7`

If I pass `a = 5` and `b = 2` then in the function add, `a` and `b` are already assigned 0, so it should return `0`. Why `7`?

Comment: You aren't passing no values. You're passing two values, `5` and `2`. `add() === 0`, as expected.

Comment: [MDN: Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters): _"Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values **if no value or `undefined` is passed**."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let add = (a = 0,b = 0) => {
    return a+b;
};

SO your function will be evaluated something like this

let add = (a, b) => {
    a = (typeof(a) !== undefined) ? a : 0; 
    b = (typeof(b) !== undefined) ? b : 0;
    return a + b; //your function code start from here.
}
```

So if you pass `add(5, 2)`, condition `(typeof(a) !== undefined)` will be true and 5 will be assign to `a` and same for `b`, but if you pass `add(5)` then condtion for `a` become ttrue and `a` is assign as 5 but condition for `b` is false so `b` will be assign as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameters are overwritten if provided by the call. Otherwise they would be useless, as you could never change them.

Answer (score 0):

That is the whole point of **default** values: if you do not provide values when calling the function, the defaults are used, otherwise the values passed in the function call are used.

```js
let add = (a = 2, b = 1) => {
  return a + b;
};

console.log(add(5, 2)); // no default will be used
console.log(add(5)); // only second default will be used
console.log(add(undefined, 4)); // only first default will be used
```

Answer (score 0):

In any language, the default value is only used when there is no other value assigned.
So, whenever you assigned any value to the variable it changes the value.

Same is going with your concept

```
let add = (a = 0,b = 0) => {
    return a+b;
};

console.log(add(5,2)); // it will return 7
console.log(add()); // it will return 0
```